# Reactjs passing data from child to parent

Tags: reactjs

There is no problem in adding the because I successfully added data to my database but the problem is need to refresh the page before getting the updated data. this is the code ive done so far, this is the current error, did i miss something in my code? please help

note:

> The child component will add data and the parent component will
> display the latest data that the child component inserted

[image]

parent

```
const OvertimeType = () => {
  const [reRender, setRerender] = useState(false);
  ....
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await getDepartmentData('All', 100, 0);
        response.data.map(function(u){
            .....
        })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [reRender]);
const HandleAdd = (val) =>{
    setRerender(val);
}
return (
    <CustomToolbar sendToParent={HandleAdd()}/>
)
...
}
```

//

child

```
class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
 
  state = false;


  HandleAdd = () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Over Time',
    text: "Input overtime name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('This field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('This field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(res =>{
        if (res.status == 200){
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Over Time',
              text: 'New Data has been added successfully.',
            }).then(res => {
              this.sendToParent(res);
            })
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={this.HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass a function as a prop, you should pass its reference (don't call it). so parent will return this -  <CustomToolbar sendToParent={HandleAdd}/>. No round parentheses in HandleAdd

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here. First, as a few others have noted you'll want to pass the function, not invoke it.

```
<CustomToolbar sendToParent={HandleAdd}/>
```

Second, in this implementation `sendToParent` is defined on `props`, rather than a function in the class. To access it, you'll need to invoke it on `this.props`.

```
this.props.sendToParent(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the way you pass the function

```
    <CustomToolbar sendToParent={HandleAdd()}/>
```

A callback function should be sent like this  without the parenthesis:

```
<CustomToolbar sendToParent={HandleAdd}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I update my code and rerun but i encounter the same problem says `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.sendToParent is not a function`